# how to get the value of another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How can I get the value of a cell in another row ( for e.g. "F" and row() - 1) ?
I want to concatenate two letters , for eg. F and 3 and then i need the value in F3.

can anyone help ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this formula was in row 4 then 
`=INDIRECT("F"&ROW()-1)`
would return the value in F3

Comment: thanks a lot. 
I was looking this
=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("F",ROW()-1))-INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("E",ROW()))